# Relational UML Diagram inspired by SO

Tags: uml, relational-database

My homework was to create a relational UML diagram about a discussion site. I used the [SO schema](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema), and I did some modifications:

- removed Age in the User Information
- added representatives, which allows users to categorise posts by their usernames (voluntary)

Otherwise, the schema is rather similar, but rudimentary. How would you improve it?

**Clarification**

The main idea of representatives is to categorise posts. The list contains only a handful possible names. In contrast to badges, the idea is not to funny, but organised. If you ask questions about Mathematics, you could be `Steve.math` or just `math`. It helps other users to see directly what you are like, and space is not wasted to you `Username`. Perhaps, there is an easier way to organise things, so don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: What does representatives represent?

Comment: "Improve" in what regard? Normalization? Decoupling? Layout of the diagram itself?

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: In this case, I don't agree, Neil.

Comment: And by the way, I get really annoyed by people that post graphical IMG links that render without my permission on SO, which is explicitly intended to be low bandwidth. Some of us are paying for these bits - in future, please just provide a normal URL.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just turn images off then, Neil?

Comment: Agreed. In this day and age, it's inconceivable that the cost of loading one image would be so much that you'd complain about it, but not just turn off images.  The image included in the homework question made me more likely to answer it.

Comment: Because sometimes I need them. I don't need any random programmer's UML designs, however. If SO degenerates into bunch of bitmaps and video clips, then include me out.

Comment: So you would suggest the OP omit the image entirely? I think he did a good job making a small image that fits within the boundaries of the question layout. Usually users aren't even that courteous. I think you're being unnecessarily oafish.

Comment: "it's inconceivable that the cost of loading one image would be so much that you'd complain about it" - from that I assume you do not live in the UK, and are not currently unemployed.

Comment: @Welbog This particular image is I suppose unexceptional, but if every post contained one?

Comment: I don't see your point. There aren't many situations which can't be explained with words. A question about a diagram is a rare occurrence on this site. I think this is the first image I've seen in a few days on SO. Possibly weeks. It's definitely not a trend, and if it grows to a trend then you should disable images if it's that much of a concern.

Comment: @welbog The time to nip things is proverbialy at the bud. And as for examples of gratuitous images, I see them every day. Look at all the book recommendations that feel the need to post completely useless, uninformative bitmaps of the cover!

Comment: You nip *problems* in the bud, Neil. Your bandwidth concern is a problem local to you and probably very few others. I definitely think we ought to encourage users like SimpleThings to post images in this kind of situation, as long as the image is well cropped (otherwise it should be linked) and relevant to the question (unlike images of book covers). I suspect that Jeff and the other moderators would agree with this as well. I maintain that if you have bandwidth concerns you should resolve them yourself rather than asking the sites you visit to solve them for you.

Comment: "You nip problems in the bud, Neil." A man who has never wielded a pair of secateurs, I suspect. You nip at, or just below the infected bud. But this I suspect is a) an argument I will lose and b) one you guys on meta will enjoy more than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Votes

Add:

```
UserID (FK)
PostID (FK)
```

#### Users

- Get rid of Upvotes and Downvotes, that is information that can come from the votes table.
- Make it an 'integer'. Unless you have a really big site, there's no need to have a GUID as a user ID.

#### Posts

- ID Should be `GUID`

#### Comments

- ID should be `GUID`

If you keep `Representatives`, I'd change the name of it. The name doesn't tell me anything about what it holds.

Otherwise, I don't think it's a good idea to keep that -- it's something that the '`tags`' can tell you, unless I'm completely missing why that exists.

Comment: "Representatives" looks more like a tag that is assigned to a user rather than to a question.

Comment: @Gortok: Actually, you can have Representatives in SO if you use many Gmail accounts. It is misleading to think SO without it. I am SimpleThings because I want to categorise my beginner questions. I am a math-quy with very mathematical questions. "Such representatives" are natural because of better replies. My math-account attracts very different people in contrast to SimpleThings. It is easier to start to follow people with descriptive name, or let's call it profile/representative -- it does not really matter. The main idea in Representatives is better order, tags are mere refinements.

Comment: For Stack Overflow, the purpose isn't to follow 'people' it's to follow types of questions, hence the tagging. "Representatives" (still dont' like the naming, If I saw that in code I'd probably go, "WTF does that mean?".  If you're building Stack Overflow's schema, it doesn't make sense to have 'representatives'.

Comment: @Gortok: I agree, but would it be easier for you if the questions were better organised? Can you really find things fast in SO even with tags and Google? Many times, I found gems in SO by accident. I would like to increase the probability.

Comment: Yes. If you use site:google.com plus your search string, you can almost be guaranteed to find it.

Comment: @SimpleThings: If you think you have a good idea to improve the usability of the site, you should post it on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ so that other users can check it out, add input and vote on it. If the idea gains enough support Jeff et al. will add it. I personally would like to see a more detailed description of "representatives" because admittedly I'm having trouble understanding the concept.

Comment: Please, note I do not oppose tags. I just feel things, such as questions, tags and even users, could be better organised with "representatives". It would bring some complexity for better order, so it is a tradeoff.

Comment: @Gortok: Thank you! I changed the name "representatives" to "profiles". I will do a test site first before submitting it to Meta. One part is missing, I  agree it. Such complexity would require better tools.